# Monkey patch and restore builtin set-window-dedicated-p during advice

Tags: functions, advice, symbol-function, dedicated-windows

I would like to make `set-window-dedicated-p` a NOP when called from `xref--show-pos-in-buf`. Below is an attempt to do so using advice. It doesn't work, I think because `fset` is not really copying the original function definition, just pointing things at each other. How can I either fix this approach to make it work, or use an alternative approach to accomplish my overall goal?

Overall goal: The way I have things set up, when I run an xref command like `xref-find-references`, buffer `*xref*` is shown in a full window which is how I like. But, when I hit `RET` to visit a reference, the location opens in a new frame. From what I can tell, this is because `xref--show-pos-in-buf` dedicates `*xref*` which seems to cause `display-buffer` to think the best solution is to display the buffer in a new frame. I *never* want a new frame, so my overall goal here is that `*xref*` and anything I select in it always open in the same frame I am already using.

```
(defun sham-set-window-dedicated-p (win flag)
  "Don't dedicate WIN, only return FLAG."
  flag)

(fset 'original-set-window-dedicated-p (symbol-function 'set-window-dedicated-p))

(defadvice xref--show-pos-in-buf (around my-xref--show-pos-in-buf activate)
  "Monkey patch set-window-dedicated-p so it doesn't do anything."
  (fset 'set-window-dedicated-p sham-set-window-dedicated-p))
  ad-do-it
  (fset 'set-window-dedicated-p (symbol-function 'original-set-window-dedicated-p)))
```

Comment: > A given function object usually appears in the function cell of only one symbol, but this is just a convention. It is easy to store it in several symbols using fset; then each of the symbols is a valid name for the same function.

from https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Names.html#Function-Names confirms the reason why this approach isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `fset` and `defalias` can point to a symbol or its current function definition, depending on whether you pass them the symbol or `symbol-function` applied to the symbol.  The latter gets the value of `symbol-function` at the time of *aliasing*.  The former gives you the value of `symbol-function` at the time the alias in *invoked* - it is essentially an indirection.

I think maybe you forgot to quote `sham-set-window-dedicated-p` here:

```
(fset 'set-window-dedicated-p sham-set-window-dedicated-p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your code will misbehave if `ad-do-it` ends up signalling an error (so the subsequent `fset` is not executed any more to restore the normal state).

Here's a slightly more verbose way to get what you want, which I think works better (e.g. it lets <kbd>C-h f</kbd> show you what's going on, and it does not misbehave when you use the new threading facilities):

```
(defvar my-inhibit-set-window-dedicated nil)
(advice-add 'set-window-dedicated-p :around
  (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
    "Add inhibitor variable `my-inhibit-set-window-dedicated'."
    (unless my-inhibit-set-window-dedicated
      (apply orig-fun args))))

(advice-add 'xref--show-pos-in-buf :around
  (lambda (orig-fun &rest args)
    "Inhibit `set-window-dedicated-p'."
    (let ((my-inhibit-set-window-dedicated t))
      (apply orig-fun args))))
```